# Unity2D GameObject Falling While Gravity Scale Set to 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, gameobject, rigid-bodies

I'm programming a top-down 2D game where the background is the ground.  Every time I test the game, my character falls down to the lower bound of the map.  Everywhere I look, people are saying that setting "Gravity Scale" to 0 will prevent this downward pull, but even with that value in place, my character falls upon playtesting.

I've attached a screenshot of the Rigidbody 2D settings for my character below.

[image]

Comment: Is there any scripts that could affect the movement? Do any other objects or forces drag it down?

Comment: we need more information regarding the components of the player object, the ground etc

Comment: The scripts that move the character have been tested, and only set movement values when the correct input is given.  The ground has an edge collider on it to prevent the player from passing through it (which works when the player falls onto it).  The player object has 2 colliders, one square, and one circular.

Comment: In further exploration, I've found that disabling the Box Collider prevents the player from falling, so it's something to do with that.  The Circle Collider is just used as a trigger, so it doesn't use the physics.  I'll add the Box Collider's information above.

Comment: When I went to get a screenshot of the Collider, I noticed that I hadn't made the projectile the character fires collisionless during its normal animation, nor given it the "Is Trigger" property.  Apparently, the character was colliding with his projectile, and it pushed him downward.  It only showed up once he hit the bottom edge, though.  That said, it's fixed.  Thank you both for your assistance, your encouragement to dig deeper allowed me to find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character's projectile has its own Circle Collider, meant to be used as a trigger.  This however was not set, and, while the projectile was not showing, it was still colliding (as I had not set it as disabled during the animation).  This meant that it would collide with the player's main Box Collider, and push it downward.